# Why headless service to be used for Kafka in Kubernetes, why not Cluster IP with load balancing out of box?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, load, load-balancing

Most of the examples I come across to use `Kafka` in `Kubernetes` is to deploy it as a `headless service` but I am not able to get the answer yet on why it should be headless and not `Cluster IP`? In my opinion cluster, IP provides the load balancing in which we ensure out of the box that not only one of the `broker` gets loaded always with its resources as I see with headless the `Kafka` clients be it sarma or java client tries to pick always the first IP from the `DNS lookup` and connects to it, will this not be a bottleneck if there are around 100+ clients trying to do the same and open connection to the first IP? or `Kafka` handles this inbuilt already which I am still trying to understand how it really happens.

Answer (score 6):

When there is no differentiation between various instances of a services(replicas of a pod serving a stateless application), you can expose them under a ClusterIP service as connecting to any of the replica to serve the current request is okay. This is not the case with stateful services(like Kafka, databases etc). Each instance is responsible for it's own data. Each instance might be owning a different partition/topic etc. The instances of the service are not exact "replicas". Solutions for running such stateful services on Kubernetes usually use headless services and/or statefulsets so that each instance of the service has a unique identity. Such stateful applications usually have their own clustering technology that rely on each instance in the cluster having a unique identity.

Now that you know why stable identities are required for stateful applications and how statefulsets with headless services provide stable identities, you can check how your Kafka distributions might using them to run Kafka on kubernetes.

[This blog post explains how strimzi does it:](https://strimzi.io/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1.html)

> For StatefulSets – which Strimzi is using to run the Kafka brokers –
> you can use the Kubernetes headless service to give each of the pods a
> stable DNS name. Strimzi is using these DNS names as the advertised
> addresses for the Kafka brokers. So with Strimzi:
>
> - The initial connection is done using a regular Kubernetes service to
>   get the metadata.
> - The subsequent connections are opened using the DNS
>   names given to the pods by another headless Kubernetes service.

Comment: `Each instance might be owning a different partition/topic etc` - can you explain more on this? Why it's might? Which means that it's not mandatory and we will be able to discover partition/topic from any broker anyways? sorry being ignorant but trying to understand this more as earlier everything was just working fine with Cluster IP for `Kafka` with 50+ consumers and producers and now after seeing the usage of headless service bit confused what's really a deal with or without this.

Comment: That is a general statement about why stateful applications might need unique identity for each replica. You need to understand how your particular kafka distribution is implemented. What are you using to install kafka on kubernetes?

Comment: helm is used to install kafka on kubernetes if that's the question was? there is 3 brokers and replication factor is 3 to ensure availability.

Answer (score 0):

It's used in cases where communication to specific Pods is needed.
For example, A monitoring service must be able to reach all pods behind a service, to check their status, so it needs the addresses of all Pods and not just any one of them. This would be a use case of headless service.

Or when there is a cluster of Pods being set up, it's important to coordinate with the Pods to keep the cluster working for consumers. In Kafka, this work is done by Zookeeper. thus a headless service is needed by Zookeeper

Answer (score -3):

---

### Stateful:

### *Kafka streaming platform maintain replicas of partition across kafka brokers based on RELICATION_FACTOR. It maintains it data across persistent storage. When it comes to K8s ; stateful type is suggested; Pods in StatefulSets are not interchangeable: each Pod has a unique identifier that is maintained no matter where it is scheduled.*

### Headless:

***To maintain internal communication between PODS. Lets not forget Zookeeper orchestrates kafka brokers.
Thanks
Within POD they should know eachother who is running and who stopped***

Comment: Why is everything bold and italicized here? Please don't shout at us. See [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Sure noted. Will keep in mind when posting next time. Thanks